# How to use ElasticSearch Query params (DSL query) for multiple types?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been working with the ElasticSearch from last few months, but still find it complicated when I have to pass an complicated query.

I want to run the query which will have to search the multiple "types" and each type has to be searched with its own "filters", but need to have combined "searched results"

For example:

I need to search the "user type" document which are my friends and on the same time i have to search the "object type" document which I like, according to the keyword provided.

OR

The query that has both the "AND" and "NOT" clause

Example query:

```
$options['query'] = array(
        'query' => array(
            'filtered' => array(
                'query' => array(
                    'query_string' => array(
                        'default_field' => 'name',
                        'query' => $this->search_term . '*',
                    ),
                ),
                'filter' => array(
                    'and' => array(
                        array(
                            'term' => array(
                                'access_id' => 2,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),

                    'not' => array(
                        array(
                            'term' => array(
                                'follower' => 32,
                            ),
                        ),

                        array(
                            'term' => array(
                                'fan' => 36,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

as this query is meant to search the user with access_id = 2, but must not have the follower of id 32 and fan of id 36

but this is not working..

**Edit: Modified query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "not": {
              "filter": {
                "and": [
                  {
                    "query": {
                      "query_string": {
                        "default_field": "fan",
                        "query": "*510*"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "query": {
                      "query_string": {
                        "default_field": "follower",
                        "query": "*510*"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "access_id": 2
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "query": {
        "field": {
          "name": "xyz*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*now after running this query, i am getting two results, one with follower: "34,518" & fan: "510" and second with fan:"34", but isn't it supposed to be only the second one in the result.*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

You may want to look at the slides of a presentation that I gave this month, which explains the basics of how the query DSL works:

[Terms of endearment - the ElasticSearch Query DSL explained](http://www.slideshare.net/clintongormley/terms-of-endearment-the-elasticsearch-query-dsl-explained)

The problem with your query is that your filters are nested incorrectly.  The `and` and `not` filters are at the same level, but the `not` filter should be under `and`:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_all/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "filtered" : {
         "filter" : {
            "and" : [
               {
                  "not" : {
                     "filter" : {
                        "and" : [
                           {
                              "term" : {
                                 "fan" : 36
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "term" : {
                                 "follower" : 32
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               },
               {
                  "term" : {
                     "access_id" : 2
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         "query" : {
            "field" : {
               "name" : "keywords to search"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

Comment: Does "not" filter always come under the "and" filter, or it is just in this case

Comment: Your edited question introduces other problems. I suggest you have a look through the presentation that I linked to - it explains the difference between terms and text, and what types of queries or filters to use where.

Comment: Hmmm I have been studying your SlideShow and doing lots of experiments over it. Mean while can you please tell if the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194823/any-good-tutorial-for-elasticsearch-query-params-dsl-query/7209726#7209726 is good to use or i should use the filers only. Thanks for you time.

Comment: Do you have a recording of this presentation?

Comment: Unfortunately no - also it's very old now. Keep an eye on elasticsearch.org, the first part of the book "The definitive guide" will be going up in the next month or so, which should help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried it with the "BOOL"

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "access_id": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "name": "xyz*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "follower": "*510*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "fan": "*510*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**It gives the correct answer.**

but I'm not sure should it be used like this ?

Comment: This will work, but is terribly inefficient.  The wildcard clauses have to load all terms, find all terms that match, then rewrite the query to include all of those terms.  That can really blow up.  It is much better to analyze your data correctly at index time, so that you can break up your values into separate terms, which you can match on individually.  You may need to look at using the ngram analyser, but it really depends on your data. Have a look at this thread for an example http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/help-needed-with-the-query-tt3177477.html#a3178856

Comment: Thanks @DrTech, it is very well explained. +1. And I would really say that you should write a Full Tutorial on ElasticSearch, because no one have done it yet :) Thanks

Comment: Any clues on how to mix a 'range' query with a 'match'.
I feel like there should be hundreds of examples of this kind of thing, but somehow nothing in the docs?